# How to access a ServletRequest from inside a singleton spring bean?

Tags: java, spring

I have a singleton spring bean that is being invoked in response to some client side action.
I wish to capture some information about the client (specifically the IP address). I assume the best source of this information is the request object. How do I obtain access to the request object from inside my bean?

Forgive me if this is an obvious question, I'm very new to Spring.

I've tried one thing without success.:

```
((ServletRequestAttributes)RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes())
.getRequest().getRemoteAddr();
```

But that failed with an IllegalStateException out of `currentRequestAttributes`. The exception text suggests using a `RequestContextListener` or `RequestContextFilter`

I've found a [reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes-other-web-configuration) to how to configure the `RequestContextListener`, but I still don't know to change my bean so I can access the request information.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`RequestContextListener` is added to `web.xml`, and this will associate the current request with the current thread. This thread association is then retrieved via `RequestContextHolder` in the way you've already tried.

So just slap `RequestContextListener` into `web.xml`, and your code should just start working:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

`RequestContextListener` is not normally required in Spring MVC apps, since `DispatcherServlet` will do it automatically. I assume this is not a Spring MVC app?

Comment: Perfect, this did work! I just had the name of the RequestContextListener in the web.xml. What does the requestDestroyed(ServletRequestEvent).attributes do?

Comment: Correct, this is not a Spring MVC app. Sorry, didn't see that the first time I read your answer.